# Jquery ajax - cannot set new values in text boxes - modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following function to bring up a `modal/dialog` when a user wants to enter a `shift` into a basic timetable grid. I use ajax to post the form, which works fine, and returns as I wish.

The problem is that when I use the function a 2nd time it uses the values I put in the `textboxes` the first time regardless of what I enter the 2nd time.

i.e.
Attempt1

- Entered in boxes 11:00:00 - 17:00:00
- values passed to php page 11:00:00 - 17:00:00

Attempt2

- Entered in boxes 14:00:00 - 22:00:00
- values passed to php page 11:00:00 - 17:00:00

I managed to get the function to clear the values with `$("#starttime").val('');`. but even when I do this, on any subsequent attempt, I can't enter new values. It just posts empty ones, regardless of what I type. It is passing all of the other variables correctly too like ``` date``week ``` and `year`.

```
function newshiftClick(eid, date, week, year) {
    $("#delete-confirm").html("Please input start and finish times for the new shift.<br>\n\
Start:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' size='8' id='starttime' placeholder='00:00:00'><br>\n\
Finish:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' size='8' id='finishtime' placeholder='00:00:00'><br>");


    $("#delete-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "New Shift",
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                var starttime = document.getElementById("starttime").value;
                var finishtime = document.getElementById("finishtime").value;
                console.log(starttime);
                console.log(finishtime);
                console.log(date);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxrequest.php",
                    data: { action: "newshift", 
                            eid: eid,
                            date: date,
                            starttime: starttime,
                            finishtime: finishtime,
                            week: week,
                            year: year
                          },
                    success: function(response) {
                        clearSchedule();
                        document.getElementById("editorpanel").innerHTML = response;
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#starttime").val('');
                        $("#finishtime").val('');

                                }

                });


                $(this).dialog('close');

            },
                "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**

This is now my ajax call. I changed it in accordance with the first answer given, which does make sense. However it doesn't actually change the behaviour like it should.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxrequest.php",
                    data: { action: "newshift", 
                            eid: eid,
                            date: date,
                            starttime: $("#starttime").val(),
                            finishtime: $("#finishtime").val(),
                            week: week,
                            year: year
                          },
                    success: function(response) {
                        clearSchedule();
                        document.getElementById("editorpanel").innerHTML = response;
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#starttime").val('');
                        $("#finishtime").val('');

                                }

                });
```

I have also tried using `$("#delete-confirm").html('');` at the end of the `success function` too.

Comment: Could it have something to do with your mixing document.getElementById("starttime").value and $("#starttime").val('');?

Comment: Where do you call $("#starttime").val(''); ?

Comment: let's say that I didn't have that in there.  Then it would still use the old values anyway.  Even though the textboxes appear clear when I bring them up a 2nd time. the `.val()` is actually doing what it's supposed to

Comment: what does console say prior to your AJAX (`console.log(starttime);`)?

Comment: @AxelAmthor nothing that's the first line on console

Comment: You are creating the div `delete-confirm` with the inputs dynamically on event. What about adding that static to the body and only toggle visibility on event?

Comment: the `div` is already in the `body`, it is a single empty div at the bottom of my page that I use for various different modals, defined by their functions. I tried putting the inputs in it static and they didn't appear in the modal. But surely, even if I close the modal, and then dynamically generate new text boxes, then the values would be empty, and ready for new input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the 2nd line after the close event for my modal did the trick in addition to the suggestion below. Given that I use the same `<div>` for various different types of content in the modal, and define the `innerhtml` when the modal is called.

```
$(this).dialog('close');
$(this).remove(); //this line
```

EDIT : 2nd option

```
$("#starttime").remove();
$("#finishtime").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
var starttime = document.getElementById("starttime").value;
var finishtime = document.getElementById("finishtime").value;
```

Those variables are getting evaluated once, when the "Yes" function gets evaluated as jQuery builds the dialog for you. Then they become a part of the closure/scope of the ajax call and that's a wrap. They become sort of immutable at that point.

In order to fix it, I would get rid of the first 5 lines of your "Yes" button handler function and change your ajax call so that it reads this way:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxrequest.php",
                data: { action: "newshift", 
                        eid: eid,
                        date: date,
                        starttime: $("#starttime").val(),
                        finishtime: $("#finishtime").val(),
                        week: week,
                        year: year
                      },
                success: function(response) {
                    clearSchedule();
                    document.getElementById("editorpanel").innerHTML = response;
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#starttime").val('');
                    $("#finishtime").val('');

                            }

            });
```

In other words, get the value our of the input at the exact time you send the request; don't preload it into a variable whose scope/closure you can't control (or don't know how to).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it didn't change the behaviour at all I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you tell me how the newshiftClick function is being used? like, when is it firing? Can you perhaps post a codepen with the whole markup and js?

Comment: Please see my answer above. I did use your answer, however what that did was keep the values at `''` the 2nd time i used the form. The fix is to completely rmove and reinstatiate the textboxes when the modal is open. Thanks for your answer thought. I have upvoted it.